# How do I use readline.question method with await?

Tags: javascript

How to make the code below work with `await`?

```
var readline = require('readline');
var Writable = require('stream').Writable;

var mutableStdout = new Writable({
  write: function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    if (!this.muted)
      process.stdout.write(chunk, encoding);
    callback();
  }
});

mutableStdout.muted = false;

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: mutableStdout,
  terminal: true
});

//add await
rl.question('Amount: ', function(password) {
  console.log('\nAmount is ' + password);
  rl.close();
});

//add await
rl.question('Secret: ', function(password) {
  console.log('\nSecret is ' + password);
  rl.close();
});

mutableStdout.muted = true;
```

`Secret` should be queried with `mutableStdout.muted` set to true, and `Amount` should be queried with `mutableStdout.muted` set to false.

The both values should be saved to the variables `amount` and `secret`.

The code should work from the console with

```
node mycode.js
```

Comment: Don't pass a callback when you want to use promises. Also read [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#rlquestionquery-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node:readline` provides a sub-module called `node:readline/promises` using a promise-based API.

Import this API instead with `require("node:readline/promises")` or ESM import from that same module. You can then `await rl.question("...")` with your desired text.

The docs show this example:

```js
import * as readline from 'node:readline/promises';
import { stdin as input, stdout as output } from 'node:process';

const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output });

const answer = await rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ');

console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);

rl.close();
```